# 8051 resets when more than 2 relays operated on port 2

Tags: controller, 8051

I want to operate 8 relays using 8051 Micro-controller. But in My program, whenever I turn ON more than 1 relay, the controller resets itself. What can be the reason? I have KA7805 voltage regulator which is capable of supplying 1A current and should not be the reason for this.I have used [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHa5x.jpg) relay module and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHa5x.jpg) 8051 board. Micro-Controller used is Philips' P89V51RD2.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks  a lot a problem in the power supply, perhaps more decoupling capacitors are need. In any case this question belongs in the electronics forum, not here.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your relays are drawing too much current from the micro controller. You might consider connecting the relay via transistor like so:

[image]

Also, this really isn't specific to 8051 programming, and should really be asked on electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Actually relay board has that provision with opto-coupler for extra isolation. Anyways thanks for the suggestion. I will try changing power supply design and will let you know.